# Using .png as icon of navigation drawer crashes app below api 21

Tags: java, android, material-design

I have created an app for api 11 and above. I used design support for Material design.
For Navigation drawer menu, i used .png images,by default there are drawable.xml foe icons, app is working fine for api >=21 but it crashes for lower version(api <=20).I'm not able to understand the problem, it took a lot of time to figure out the issue, app crash was giving unable to inflate NavigationView widget.